# PHP 7 and Doctrine Group Uses

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, php-7

I want to use some features of PHP 7 but I'm kinda struggling with it.

I have a Symfony-Project using Doctrine to map some Entities. New in PHP 7 are the GROUP USE-Statemens, which I wanted to try. But it seems I'm doing something wrong, since Symfony / Doctrine can't resolve the Annotations in the Entity-Object.

**Use-Statement:**

```
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\{Entity, Id, Table, Column, GeneratedValue, JoinColumn, OneToOne, ManyToMany, JoinTable};
```

**Entity**

```
/**
 * @Entity
 * @Table(name="expansion")
 */
class Expansion {
..
}
```

**Exception**

```
[Semantical Error] The annotation "@Entity" in class AppBundle\Entity\Expansion was never imported. Did you maybe forget to add a "use" statement for this annotation?
```

If I use the single USE-Statements, the import works perfectly...

What am I doing wrong? Versions are correct. Also PHPStorm is saying that 'Alias XY' is never used.

Thanks for your support!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm not 100% sure but I bet that the `Doctrine\Common\Annotations` component cannot handle PHP7 grouped `use` statements yet. I could not find any written statement that confirms this assumption but [`Doctrine\Common\Annotations\TokenParser::parseUseStatement`](https://github.com/doctrine/annotations/blob/v1.2.7/lib/Doctrine/Common/Annotations/TokenParser.php#L100) does not seem to handle grouped namespaces at all.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It seems like this... Since, I'm new to Doctrine: What do you recommend to do to solve that issue? Can/Should I open a bug on the Doctrine-page?

Comment: @iChaos Stefan's answer is correct. I added a pull request that should address it, but it won't be included right away: https://github.com/doctrine/annotations/pull/69 . For now if you're working on this project yourself, you can just patch your `vendor/doctrine/annoations/lib/Doctrine/Common/Annotations/TokenParser.php` with these changes: https://github.com/poldridge/annotations/commit/c5c88bb690736dfc3e4b5229972dabfbb792bab0 and it should start working.

Comment: @Paulpro: Thanks a lot :D